# Which of the two is grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

'Remind me to tell you about my favorite movies' 
'Remind me to tell you my favorite movies'

Which of the two sentences is grammatically correct? and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are acceptable grammatically, but I would take a different meaning from them.

If I heard the first, "tell you about my favourite movies" would lead me to expect a detailed description of the speakers favourite movies - the plot, the characters, why they like them etc.

The second, "tell you my favourite movies" would have me expecting a nice, short, "my favourite movies are A, B, and C".